# Returning ContentResult for Ajax Response has extra tags in .NET MVC controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a Controller Action that is trying to return plain text to an AJAX call.  E.G.-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SubmitAttachment(int id, HttpPostedFileBase theFile){
...
...
   return Content("Success");
}
```

In my javascript function which is doing the ajax call, I am expecting the response text to just be "Success", but I'm getting `"<head></head><body>Success</body>"` instead.

In 99% of my other controller actions, I don't have this issue.  The only thing that I can think of that makes this different is because the AJAX call to "SubmitAttachment" is a form POST with the "enctype=multipart/form-data", where as the other AJAX calls aren't uploading any files.

Has anyone encountered this before?  If so...how would I just have it return plain text?

NOTE: I have also tried `return Content("Success", "text/plain")`, but that just adds additional `<pre></pre>` tags around the "Success" string.

Comment: I think the `pre` tags - and the other stuff you're seeing - aren't really there, but just added by your browser. Use Fiddler and/or curl to test instead of just a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unable to reproduce the behavior:

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int id, HttpPostedFileBase theFile)
    {
        return Content("Success", "text/plain");
    }
}
```

View:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%: Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js") %>"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('form').submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="id" value="4" />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

When the form is submitted the server returns only `"Success"`.

Comment: The <pre> stuff is added by @TWong's browser. But I guess you know this already. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do what bzlm suggested, using fiddler to test it out to make sure those tags are actually coming back that way. If they still are, try returning a plain string instead. Set the return type to string and then return "success" without the Content(). If you are still getting tags around it when returning a string then you are in an alternate reality where things that are not possible are somehow possible.

Comment: I was suspecting the same thing, that the tags were browser related, but it's just strange that the browser doesn't inject tags for all my other controller actions that just do "return Content(...)".

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure why it's doing that. What browser is it?

Comment: FireFox is the broswer I'm testing in